# Difference between Container port and targetport in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, port, kubernetes-pod

How is `container port` different from `targetports` in a container in Kubernetes?
Are they used interchangeably, if so why?

I came across the below code snippet where `containerPort` is used to denote the `port` on a pod in Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: demo-voting-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: postgres-pod
      app: demo-voting-app
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postgres-pod
      labels:
        name: postgres-pod
        app: demo-voting-app

    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:9.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
```

In the above code snippet, they have given 5432 for the `containerPort` parameter (in the last line). So, how is this `containerPort` different from `targetport`?

As far as I know, the term `port` in general refers to the `port` on the `service` (Kubernetes). Correct me if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Are you talking about port and targetPort in Kubernetes service?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu Yes!!

Comment: I wanted to know if the term containerport and the term port meant the same or not!

Comment: Edit the question and add an example yaml to clarify which port and container port you are referring to

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu
I have added a code snippet and a few more lines. I think this would make my question eligible to stay open for the community to help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**In a nutshell:** `targetPort` and `containerPort` basically refer to the same port (so if both are used they are expected to have the same value) but they are used in two different contexts and have entirely different purposes.

They cannot be used interchangeably as both are part of the specification of two distinct kubernetes resources/objects: `Service` and `Pod` respectively. While the purpose of `containerPort` can be treated as purely informational, `targetPort` is required by the `Service` which exposes a set of `Pods`.

It's important to understand that by declaring `containerPort` with the specific value in your `Pod`/`Deployment` specification you cannot make your `Pod` to expose this specific port e.g. if you declare in `containerPort` field that your nginx `Pod` exposes port `8080` instead of default `80`, you still need to configure your nginx server in your container to listen on this port.

Declaring `containerPort` in `Pod` specification is optional. Even without it your `Service` will know where to direct the request based on the info it has declared in its `targetPort`.

It's good to remember that it's not required to declare `targetPort` in the `Service` definition. If you omit it, it defaults to the value you declared for `port` (which is the port of the `Service` itself).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, it is documented anywhere in kubernetes docs?

Comment: This is very critical information for me. Thanks for answering in detail. Can you share Kubernetes documentation for the same?

Answer (score 11):

**ContainerPort in pod spec**

List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed

**targetPort in service spec**

Number or name of the port to access on the pods targeted by the service. Number must be in the range 1 to 65535. Name must be an IANA_SVC_NAME. If this is a string, it will be looked up as a named port in the target Pod's container ports. If this is not specified, the value of the 'port' field is used (an identity map).

Hence `targetPort` in service needs to match the `containerPort` in pod spec because that's how service knows which container port is destination to forward the traffic to.

Comment: Where does it state that port name must conform to IANA_SVC_NAME? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service uses http-web-svc as a name.  It needs to map what you have defined in container port

Answer (score 3):

**containerPort** is the port, which app inside the container can be reached on.

**targetPort** is the port, which is exposed in the cluster and the service connects the pod to other services or users.